# Partitioning of Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, partitioning

I have a cluster consisting of 1 master 10 worker nodes. When I set number of partition as 3, I wonder that does the master node use only 3 worker nodes or use all of them? Because it shows that all of them are used.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not so clear about what are you asking, However following things might help

When you start the job with 10 executors, spark application master gets all the resource from yarn. So all the executors are already associated with the spark job.

However if your data partition is less than the number of executors available, the rest of the executors will be sitting idle. Hence it is not a good idea keeping the number of partition less than the executor count.